# mwc-textfield input pattern not working for backslash or vertical bar

Tags: javascript, typescript, html-input, material-components, lit

I am trying to add a pattern to a mwc-textfield input to filter a file name. My pattern seems to be valid js regex and seems to work on a html input but does not as a pattern on a mwc-textfield. I have two problems:

1. `\|` or \ gives `Pattern attribute value ^[^|\/:*"<>]+$ is not a valid regular expression: ect...` but `\\|` works which confuses me
2. `\\` never actually seems to match no matter what I try.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-field-jjpvjz

Regex:    `^[^\|\\\/:\*&quot;&lt;&gt;]+$`

Can anyone explain this weirdness or what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're writing the regex pattern within the JS tagged template string, you need to escape the `\`, so you should double it.

```js
html`
      <mwc-textfield
        outlined
        validationMessage="WRONG!"
        pattern='^[^\\|\\\\\\/:*&quot;&lt;&gt;]+$'
        label="Test"
        value="Hello|"
      >
      </mwc-textfield>
    `
```

Comment: Where can I read up more about why this is?

Comment: Escape sequence section of String Literal here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#string_literals
An alternative solution would also be to use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) which doesn't process escape sequences so `\` wouldn't need escaping.